# How to create Web Service for ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I made application in ASP.NET MVC3 and I want to connect application with Android. 
So first step is to make Web Service, that will communicate with Android. 
But I'm new in this area and I don't know how to start. 
Does anyone have some tutorial for making Web Service for ASP.NET MVC3 application? 
Also I need instructions for connecting Android with that Web Service?

Comment: For Android use GSON (Google's library for reading JSON), here is an  [awesome tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Comment: looks like ASP.Net WebAPI would do the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really have two questions here, and unfortunately the Android one is a little too broad to answer quickly. So... let's tackle your first question.

In MVC it is pretty easy to create a simple web service. Create a controller and return JSON from it:

```
public class PersonController: Controller{

   public JsonResult Index(){
      var personList = GetFromDB();

      return Json(personList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

   [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
   public JsonResult CreatePerson(Person newPerson){
      var insertedPerson = InsertIntoDB(newPerson);

      return Json(insertedPerson);
   }

}
```

Now, with the default routing in place you can simply call those methods with the following URL, and the appropriate [HTTP Verb](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

```
http://www.mydomain.com/person
```

However, it may be worth mentioning this is far easier to do using [ASP.Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api).